# Multiple Consumers in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, json, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

I am fairly new to RabbitMQ and I am posed with a task that needs below situation be implemented.

I have a RabbitMQ producer which produces 2 kinds of messages(JSONObject).
I want these to be picked by 2 consumers(one for each type of message). There is no specific order in which the producer produces and publishes the messages.

Elaboration:

- JSONObject Type 1 has key-value pair - "service":"service1".
  JSONObject Type 2 has key-value pair - "service":"service2"
- There is no specific order in which these messages are produced.
- Type 1 Messages are supposed to be consumed by Consumer 1.
  Type 2 Messages are supposed to be consumed by Consumer 2
- If Consumer 1 cannot consume Type 1 Message, it should **not** be consumed by Consumer 2. It should remain in the queue waiting for Consumer 1.

Is there a way to achieve this using single queue?

If not, how can this be done?

Comment: You can use different queues for the same.

Comment: Have the publisher use a routing key for type 1, and a different routing key for type 2, then bind one queue per type, and finally have the corresponding consumer on each queue.

Comment: Just publish your messages to seperate queues.